# Why are there no kernel upgrades available (Debian Wheezy)

Tags: debian, apt, kernel

I'm trying to patch a server that I have confirmed is vulnerable to dirty COW. There are numerous guides other there that recommend the following, but there are no packages available.

```
# sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Hit http://ftp.uk.debian.org wheezy Release.gpg
Hit http://ftp.uk.debian.org wheezy-updates Release.gpg                       
Hit http://ftp.uk.debian.org wheezy Release                                   
Hit http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php55 Release.gpg                       
Hit http://ftp.uk.debian.org wheezy-updates Release                           
Hit http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php55 Release                           
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release.gpg            
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates Release
Hit http://ftp.uk.debian.org wheezy/main Sources
Hit http://ftp.uk.debian.org wheezy/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ftp.uk.debian.org wheezy/main Translation-en
Hit http://ftp.uk.debian.org wheezy-updates/main Sources          
Hit http://ftp.uk.debian.org wheezy-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://ftp.uk.debian.org wheezy-updates/main Translation-en/DiffIndex
Hit http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php55/all amd64 Packages    
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main Sources        
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php55/all Translation-en_GB
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy-php55/all Translation-en   
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/non-free amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/contrib Translation-en
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.debian.org wheezy/updates/non-free Translation-en
Reading package lists... Done              
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

# uname -rv
3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.41-2+deb7u2
```

What I am missing? It looks to me like I'm hitting the security update repos for wheezy.

### Update:

It looks like I was reading the package name and not the kernel version number:

```
# apt-cache policy linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64 linux-image-amd64
linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64:
  Installed: 3.2.82-1
  Candidate: 3.2.82-1
  Version table:
 *** 3.2.82-1 0
        500 http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.2.78-1 0
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
linux-image-amd64:
  Installed: 3.2+46
  Candidate: 3.2+46
  Version table:
 *** 3.2+46 0
        500 http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Having said that `uname -ir` still displays the following even after a reboot:

```
# uname -ir
3.2.0-4-amd64 unknown
```

Comment: My guess would be that either you have kernel updates excluded from apt-get for some reason, or that the new kernel just hasn't made it's way downstream to your particular distro yet. Have you tried doing `sudo apt-get install kernel`?

Comment: I've not got any packages pinned, which I think would be the only way to exclude kernel updates. I've also not got another kernel available in the cache.

Comment: BTW, you might want to consider using the repos suggested on the LTS page.  - https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Using You all have the country specific version, but the updated links are generally a better choice.

Comment: @ChrisPowell Debian/Ubuntu kernel packages are named something like `linux-image-arch` for the meta package that pulls in the latest, or `linux-image-version-arch` for the actual kernel package.

Comment: What do you see for `apt-cache policy linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64 linux-image-amd64`?

Comment: `which I think would be the only way to exclude kernel updates` - Pinning is not the only way to block updates, you can mark packages in a 'hold' state, which will prevent updates.  But these would normally be mentioned in the output of `apt-get dist-upgrade` as being held.

Comment: Are you using a VPS from D.O.?

Comment: What's in your /etc/apt/sources.list file?

Comment: @Zoredache Thanks for the info! I'm a Red Hat man myself, not too terribly familiar with Debian.

Comment: @Zoredache it looks like the cache policy calls the package `linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64` but the version number for this is `Installed: 3.2.82-1` which I believe is the patched version. So I guess I'm ok after all. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ondra Sniper Flidr's response suggested that Wheezy was already end-of-life at the time the question was posted near the end of October 2016.

That wasn't true: Wheezy continued receiving security updates and community support via Debian's Long Term Support initiative until the end of May 2018.

Wheezy's official LTS repositories did, indeed, publish a patch against Dirty COW.

Answer (score -1):

It's because Debian Wheezy is already after end-of-life and has no support from debian community, so no updates here (at least from oficial repos).